# Is it permissible from the point of view of Islam to engage in the development and training of neural networks?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it permissible from the point of view of Islam to engage in the development and training of neural networks? And is it allowed to use neural networks?

After all, by creating large neural networks (ChatGPT, for example), we create an entity capable of thinking in some sense. At the same time, we are able to make adjustments to the work of neural networks by adding new training data or directly changing the parameters of the neural network itself: topology, weights, activation functions, etc.

It turns out, in my opinion, that we thereby become like the Creator Allah.